# Detect a connected USB-C charger cable that is not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mojave, charging

Is it possible to detect a connected USB-C charger cable that is not charging?

I mean a fully functional MacBook and a charger that is connected to a power outlet, where power is disabled. I would like to do it either by some OS (userspace functionality) or information if that would be possible programatically.

I'm using MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: The battery indicator in the menu bar shows if the machine is charging or not.  Is that what you need?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm interesting in deceting it programatically (using either some software designed to watch for it or using OS-level APIs).

Comment: What do you want to actually do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for example show notification that USB-C charging cable is connected but doesn't charge the computer.

Comment: I do not know if a cable connected to an _unpowerered_ charger can be detected by the hardware.  If not, then no software can help.

Comment: @syntagma Do you want to detect a powered charger, that is not delivering power to the computer? (this is possible), or do you want to detect an unpowered charger? (this is generally not possible)

Answer (score 1):

In about this Mac, overview -> System Report -> Power, last block displays connected and charging info. Cannot comment on programmatically retrieving.

[image]